# How to generate coherent data with Rails Faker gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, faker

In order to populate my Rails application with fake data I often do this:

```
person = Person.create(
  :first_name   => Faker::Name.first_name,
  :last_name    => Faker::Name.last_name,
  :email        => Faker::Internet.email
)
```

This might produce a `person` like:

> First name: Olivia
>
> Last name: Kubera
>
> Email: milan_nieklauson@bachmannjacob.net

Is there a way to generate more coherent fake data like:

> First name: Olivia
>
> Last name: Kubera
>
> Email: olivia_kubera@aol.com

Or will I have to come up with something of my own to achieve this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can pass a name to [`Faker::Internet.email`](http://rubydoc.info/github/stympy/faker/master/Faker/Internet#email-class_method) to generate a fake email address for that person. You'll have to do a bit more work but not too much:

```
first_name = Faker::Name.first_name
last_name = Faker::Name.last_name
person = Person.create(
  :first_name => first_name
  :last_name => last_name
  :email => Faker::Internet.email(first_name + "." + last_name)
)
```

Comment: what about a `gender` attribute?